# Overlap of symbol and caption in the footnote when using \thanks in ACL template

Tags: footnotes, titles, author

I noticed that when using `\thanks{}` in the `\author{}` section, the asterisk would overlap with the caption in the footnote, as shown in the following figure. Any idea what's going on with this command in the ACL template?

[image]

```
\author{First Author\thanks{Test} \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\}
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is indeed a bit strange. The problem is that the footnotemark is placed too far to the right, and the text is placed at the normal position (i.e., *Test* starts at the same place as the url in footnote 1).

Apparently ACL also noticed this and tried to create a macro `\Thanks` (with upper case T) that adds an extra space at the start of the thanks footnote (as defined in `acl.sty` on line 128). However, first of all this does not work (the space gets gobbled somehow) and second of all the * mark is still incorrectly positioned even if you put an actual space there, for example `\author{First Author\thanks{\enspace Test}\\`.

A manual solution with correct spacing below, that adds a literal * in the author name and a footnote as part of the main document but with the * mark:

```
\author{First Author*\\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begingroup\def\thefootnote{*}\footnotetext{Test}\endgroup
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Have been finding a solution for this.